# How can I gain permission in HealthKit for writing workout routes?

Tags: permissions, watchkit, cllocationmanager, healthkit

I'm trying to add map data to my saved runs and bike rides for an Apple Watch app. I'm using CLLocationManager and HKWorkoutRouteBuilder.

Apple seems to have a pretty decent guide on building workout routes [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/workouts_and_activity_rings/creating_a_workout_route). However, I'm struggling with the sentence in the documentation that says: "Specifically for route data, you must request permission to read and share both HKWorkout and HKWorkoutRoute samples."

Below are my app's current permissions. I know I still need "Workout Routes" to show up as an option, but am struggling to do so. On top of that, I'm not exactly sure if there are other permissions that I would need to obtain as well. [image]

Thank you so much for your help!!
-David

Answer (score 15):

Whelp... this seems to answer my question!

```
let sampleTypes: Set<HKSampleType> = [
    HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .heartRate)!,
    HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .activeEnergyBurned)!,
    HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceWalkingRunning)!,
    HKSampleType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .distanceCycling)!,
    HKSeriesType.workoutType(),
    HKSeriesType.workoutRoute(),
]
```

Just had to add the last two lines to the array of sample types. I hope this helps at least one other person!